# Erro array php multidimensional

Tags: php, array

Estou tentando encontrar a diferença entre os arrays multidimensionais mas apresenta esses erros:

Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\server\htdocs\Sistema\testes.php on line 319

Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\server\htdocs\Sistema\testes.php on line 319

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
$array_1 = array(
    array( 'nome' => 'Alexandre',   'idade' => '65' ),
    array( 'nome' => 'camila',    'idade' => '33' ),
    array( 'nome' => 'Zezinha', 'idade' => '29' ),
    array( 'nome' => 'Rosana',  'idade' => '64' )
);
$array_2 = array(
    array( 'nome' => 'Alexandre',   'idade' => '65' ),
    array( 'nome' => 'camila',    'idade' => '33' )
);
print_r( array_diff_assoc( $array_1, $array_2) );
```

Comment: Você está passando dois *arrays* sequenciais (que possuem *array* associativos) para uma função que compara *arrays* associativos. O que pretendia fazer com esse código?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss quero separar os nomes que não são se repetem, tem que imprimir Zezinha e Rosana, ele faz isso, mas da o erro acima.

Comment: E o que fazer com a idade? Deve ser comparada também?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss acho que não tem necessidade, porque a idade já vem atrelada ao nome, então separando por nome, automaticamente já separa a idade correspondente!

Comment: Mas e se houverem duas Camilas com idades distintas?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não havia pensado nisso! Então se for possível comparar também o nome igual pela idade diferente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diferença entre `array_diff` e `array_diff_assoc` é que a segunda compara também o índice. No seu caso, como são dois *arrays* de índice numérico (por vezes chamados de sequenciais) onde, aparentemente, não importa qual índice o valor está. Se `Alexandre/65` for o primeiro em um *array* e o último no outro não faz diferença, é o mesmo registro, então ***deveria*** utilizar `array_diff`.

Porém, como consta na [documentação oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php):

> **Nota**:
>
> Dois elementos são considerados iguais se, e somente se, `(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2`. Em palavras: quando a representação da *string* é a mesma.

E é aqui que mora o problema. Os seus elementos são *array* e não podem ser convertidas para *string* desta maneira; e é isso que justifica a mensagem de erro que você teve:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in ...

Por que a linguagem compara os valores como *string*? Não sei, deve existir algum motivo (ou não...). Para resolver isso você deverá fazer manualmente:

```
$diff = [];

foreach ($array_1 as $arr) {
    if (!in_array($arr, $array_2)) {
        $diff[] = $arr;
    }
}

print_r($diff);
```

Com isso a saída seria:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nome] => Zezinha
            [idade] => 29
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nome] => Rosana
            [idade] => 64
        )

)
```

A função `in_array` se baseia na comparação frouxa entre os elementos, `==`, mas pode utilizar a restrita, `===`, se o terceiro parâmetro, `strict`, for definido como verdadeiro.

---

Uma alternativa é implementar manualmente a função de comparação e utilizar [`array_udiff`](https://php.net/array_udiff):

```
function compare_array($a, $b)
{
  return $a <=> $b;
}

$diff = array_udiff($array_1, $array_2, 'compare_array');
```

O resultado seria o mesmo. Com função anônima ficaria:

```
$diff = array_udiff($array_1, $array_2, function ($a, $b) {
  return $a <=> $b;
});
```

Comment: Sensacional tanto a explicação como o resultado final do código. Não sabia que precisaria fazer manualmente, pensei que as funções dos arrays na DOC resolveria. Obrigado Anderson

Comment: Estava vendo algo  mesmo da função com callback. E como eu faria para ordernar por nome? Teria como imprimir em ordem alfabetica? Igual nesse caso Rosana viria no indice 0

Comment: Consegui usando seu exemplo de função anonima , mas usando o uasort 

 
uasort($diff, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['nome'] > $b['nome'];
});

Comment: @ThiagoMoreira Sim, desta forma mesmo. Como os *arrays* possuem o mesmo tamanho, o operador `<=>` irá comparar valor a valor, então ele ordenará primeiro por nome e, entre nomes iguais, ordenará pela idade.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda.